# Result of consuming a Future with future.then() seems to only live inside the .then function()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor, flutter-future

I am building an app as a project for university and one of the requirements is to play videos within the app.

I have links to exercise videos (bicep curls and so on) stored in a column of a table in SQLite.

I am using Moor in order to interact with the database.

I have the following screen where I am trying to have the video referred in the link from the database play:

```
class ExerciseVideoTab extends StatefulWidget {
    final int exerciseId;

    ExerciseVideoTab(this.exerciseId);

    @override
    _ExerciseVideoTabState createState() => _ExerciseVideoTabState();
}

class _ExerciseVideoTabState extends State<ExerciseVideoTab> {
    VideoPlayerController _controller;
    Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
    String _exerciseVideoLink;
    
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      locator<MoorDB>().getExerciseById(widget.exerciseId).then((value) => 
                        _exerciseVideoLink = value.exerciseVideoLink);
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(_exerciseVideoLink.toString());
      _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

      print(_exerciseVideoLink); // prints null for some reason
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
            // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
              // loading spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }
         )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
          // correct icon is shown.
          setState(() {
            // If the video is playing, pause it.
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              // If the video is paused, play it.
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to consume the `Future<Exercise>` that is returned by the `getExerciseById(int id)` method and assign the `exerciseVideoLink` column value to the local `_exerciseVideoLink` and then use that String to initialize the `VideoPlayerController` with the link contained within.

The implementation of `getExerciseById(int id)` is the following:

```
    Future<Exercise> getExerciseById(int id) {
        return (select(exercises)..where((exercise) => exercise.exerciseId.equals(id))).getSingle();
    }
```

My problem right now is that after consuming the `Future<Exercise>` and assigning its exerciseVideoLink attribute to the local String variable, the variable becomes null as soon as the `.then((value) => ...` function is over and thus, the initialization of the `VideoPlayerController` fails because the URI is null.

Why is that? How can I make it so that I can consume the `Future<Exercise>` and use its `exerciseVideoLink` in order to pass it to the `VideoPlayerController`?

Comment: Your `print(_exerciseVideoLink);` statement executes *before* the `Future` completes. `.then()` just registers a success callback; it does not defer execution of subsequent statements.  Any code that depends on completion of the `Future` would need to be in the `.then()` callback (or you would need to use `await`, which is syntactic sugar that does it for you). However, `initState` is not expected to be asynchronous; you instead will need to use a `FutureBuilder`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/.

Comment: I understand. I tried this approach before trying the `.then()` route. The problem with using a `FutureBuilder` for the video link is the fact that the video player also uses a `FutureBuilder` and I am not sure how to nest them so as to make both work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_controller` depends on the result of `getExerciseById()` so you need to wait for that `Future` to complete before you can assign it. You may find `async`/`await` syntax a bit easier to read when working with lots of nested `Future`s.

An example implementation could be:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _init();  // split out a separate method, initState cannot be async
}

Future<void> _init() async {
  final exercise = await locator<MoorDB>().getExerciseById(widget.exerciseId);
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(exercise.exerciseVideoLink.toString());
  _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When I reload the screen, I get the following error:
`The getter 'value' was called on null`; it refers to the _controller.value calls, so _controller is still null.